# Python Discord OAuth2 - Guild.Join (Joining a Guild)

Tags: python, discord

Hi I'm trying to do a 'Authorize with Discord' that automatically joins the user to my guild.

I'm running a `Flask` application that handles all of these.

So far, here's my code:

```
def add_to_guild(access_token, userID, guildID):
        url = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/{guildID}/members/{userID}"

        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bearer {access_token}"
        }

        response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers)
        print(response.text)
```

However this doesn't work. I get a error message saying:

```
{"message": "405: Method Not Allowed", "code": 0}
```

On the OAuth2 docs, it says that i'm suppose to get a response of `201` if the user successfully joins, or `204` if user is already in the guild.

**UPDATE 1**:
I changed the method to `requests.get` and now I receive this error:

```
{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}
```

**UPDATE 2**:
I created a Bot, invited it to my discord guild and successfully was able to get some information about my user in the guild. however once i left and try to run the link again, i got this error

```
{"message": "Unknown Member", "code": 10007}
```

**UPDATE 3**:
I changed the method to PUT and now I'm getting a Bad Request

```
def add_to_guild(access_token, userID):
        url = f"{Oauth.discord_api_url}/guilds/{guildid i cant show}/members/{userID}"

        botToken = "cant show also"

        headers = {
            "Authorization" : f"Bot {botToken}",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }


        response = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers)
        print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a member, you should use `requests.put()`, and the Guilds Auth header needs to be a `Bot` token, so change to:

```
headers = {
        "Authorization" : f"Bot {access_token}"
    }
```

And make sure you are passing a Bot token.  More at:  https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference

> The Authorization header must be a Bot token (belonging to the same
> application used for authorization), and the bot must be a member of
> the guild with CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE permission.

To get the member, you would use `requests.get()` without the `bot` header.

Comment: So are you saying I have to make a Bot and it has to be a member of the Guild i'm trying to add members to ?

Comment: can you look under Update 2 of my post. I've just updated it

Comment: Did you click the links and read: `Using a bot token gained by registering a bot, for more information on bots see bots vs user accounts.`

Comment: Trust me. I've looked everywhere. It doesn't work. I'm trying to add a user to a guild not get details about the user in that guild :/

Comment: To add a member, use `requests.put()` with `bot `header.  See edit.  The docs in the link are pretty clear.

Comment: Yes I've changed it to PUT since, and now i'm getting a Bad Request :/. I'll update the question here. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

**Update 3** put() is the way to go
However, you're still missing the JSON payload which must include the user access token received from the token exchange from a code grant.

```json
data = {
        "access_token" : access_token
    }
```

Then fire your request with passing data to json, so

```py
response = requests.put(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(response.json)
```